# All of the queries vs all the queries that you may have

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Let's say you are an appointment setter. Then you said (from your company's script) this line to your potential client.

> "Hello, I'm gonna ask you only 3 questions to verify the information that we have here, then we will connect you to our specialist to answer **all OF the queries that you may have."**

Vs.

> "Hello, I'm gonna ask you only 3 questions to verify the information that we have here, then we will connect you to our specialist to answer **all the queries that you may have."**

I don't see any difference here, I need help which should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely omit the preposition "of" in your first example. It doesn't change the meaning. See this link for a discussion of omitting "of."

[When can we omit the preposition "of" in such cases?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/153763/when-can-we-omit-the-preposition-of-in-such-cases)

Also, I would advise you, in business settings or wherever you care about the impression you make with your speech, don't say "gonna." Say, "I'm going to."

Comment: Why should I not use contracted words in business? That's a nice tip, care to share?

Comment: Contractions such as "Don't," "Won't," "Can't" are fine. But contractions such as "gonna," "wanna," and "ain't," are seen as incorrect and not a sign of educated speech. Why? I don't know. I can't tell you why some are acceptable and some aren't. Perhaps that might be a good idea for your next ELL question. 